# Bootstrap validation not working - simple form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrapvalidator

I have a simple form and I want to use Bootstrap validation.
I included all requirements (jquery.js,bootstrap.js,bootstrap.min.js,bootstrap.css,bootstrap.min.css,bootstrapValidator.js,bootstrapValidator.css) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/layout/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="assets/layout/scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="assets/layout/scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/layout/styles/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/layout/styles/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/layout/scripts/bootstrap_value/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/layout/styles/bootstrap_value/bootstrapValidator.css" type="text/css" />
```

my simple form :

```
<form id="signup_form"  action="do.php"  method="post" style="text-align: center">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">نام کاربری</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">رمز ورود</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pass"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>


</form>
```

my scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#signup_form').bootstrapValidator({
            live: 'submitted',
            fields: {

                username: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: '.نام خود را وارد کنید'
                        }
                    }
                },
                pass: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: '.رمز کاربری خود را وارد کنید'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

by empty fields, after click on `submit` button, form goes on `do.php` file.

**updated**:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/layout/scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/layout/styles/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/layout/scripts/bootstrap_value/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/layout/styles/bootstrap_value/bootstrapValidator.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: 2 jQuery and 2 bootsrap JS library in header, should include only one of each library, check browser console log for errors

Comment: here is the fiddle with your code https://jsfiddle.net/na5tutyc/, its all working, check your browser console log for errors, jQuery and Bootstrap lib should include once, There is nothing wrong with your code

Comment: sideNote: using updated bootstrapValidator lib, which you can find here https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-validator